# How to apply a patch to kernel to use bluetooth dongle in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, patch

I've started using linux just a couple months back so I don't have that much experience.

It seems that my bluetooth dongle:

`lsusb`

`Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)`

needs a patch to work properly and, apparently, this one works  ''https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/bluetooth/patch/6bce2c08-48f0-f49c-d70c-280475220550@gmail.com/''

But every tutorial I find doesn't seem to quite grasp what I intend. Can someone please tell me the step by step of applying this patch? thx

Comment: Given that you "just started using Linux", the easiest, safest, most likely to succeed,  method is to wait until this patch gets merged with the mainline kernel. OTOH, I mistrust your "seems that ...  needs a patch" reasoning. Why do you think that? Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you plug in the dongle. Edit your Question to add data, don't respond in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would install Mainline a utility to install mainline kernels for Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Launch Mainline and install the 4.9.11 kernel and reboot.  The 4.9.11 kernel already has that patch installed